# VCL built-in object to subroutine mapping

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

There are several Built in subroutines in VCL ;

vcl_recv,vcl_pipe,vcl_pass,vcl_hit,vcl_miss and so on;
*ref. https://varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/users-guide/vcl-built-in-subs.html*

Can anyone tell me 
which built-in objects are accessible from which subroutine. ?
*(perhaps in tabular format)*

Answer (score 2):

You can find this information [here](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/reference/vcl.html?highlight=req%20backend_hint#variables), e.g.:

> bereq.backend
>
> Type: BACKEND
>
> Readable from: vcl_pipe, backend
>
> Writable from: vcl_pipe, backend
>
> This is the backend or director we attempt to fetch from.